# MySQL updating same table after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

Consider the following table `couples` which `male` is the primary key:

```
male female
David Maria
John Victoria
Paul Sara
Steve Anna
```

Now, suppose you create an after insert trigger:

```
BEGIN    
    UPDATE `couples` SET `female`='Brenda'
    WHERE `male`='Peter';    
END
```

At first, you might think that inserting a new male record `Peter` would make the trigger to automatically fill the female counterpart as `Brenda`. However, this is not the case:

```
INSERT INTO `couples` (`male`) VALUES ('Peter');

MySQL said:    
#1442 - Can't update table 'couples' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

According to several other posts, this is to avoid a recursive loop.

**Issue**
Each time you insert a new male record, it is necessary to fill the female counterpart. However, this should be executed only if a new record was actually created (reason why after trigger was chosen).
Is it possible to do that in MySQL? Any workaround?
Or this should be done in the application level?

Comment: Just use `SET NEW.female='Brenda'` without the `update` and so on.

Comment: @juergend MySQL said: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Change it to `before`

Comment: @juergend It is important that this process of filling the blanks happens only if a new record is actually created (reason why after trigger was chosen). Otherwise, several procedure calls would be requested unnecessarily.

Comment: I think you don't get the difference between before and after trigger. Both are only called if a record is created.

Comment: @juergend Suppose the table already have a male record `Peter`. If you try to insert another `Peter`, before trigger would be activated but after trigger not.

Comment: @juergend Observe that `male` is the primary key. You can't insert twice `Peter`. Therefore, after won't be activated in the second time you tried to insert `Peter`, but before will be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each time you insert a new male record, it is necessary to fill the female counterpart. However, this should be executed only if a new record was actually created (reason why after trigger was chosen).

The requirement for the change to be applied only if the row is created is unnecessary, because the row won't be created if it violates a constraint, regardless of whether you modify a value in the NEW row or not.

As @juergend commented above, change the female column with a `SET` statement in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

```
BEGIN    
    SET NEW.`female` = CASE NEW.`male` WHEN 'Peter' THEN 'Brenda' END;
END
```

If the INSERT is a primary key violation, the whole INSERT will be cancelled, and the whole row you tried to insert will be discarded, along with the modified value set in the BEFORE INSERT trigger.

If the INSERT is *not* a primary key violation, the row will be inserted successfully, and it will include the value you set in the BEFORE INSERT trigger.

You cannot change column values in an AFTER trigger.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html says:

> In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to update a row. (**Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.**)

(emphasis mine)

---

You seem to be focused on avoiding assigning a value to the `female` column, so I guess it's not just a simple assignment of 'Brenda'. I guess you are concerned because it must be a costly SQL query.

I suggest in that case that you need to make it a *quick* SQL query. Optimize whatever lookup you need to do to find the value of 'Brenda' so it's not a big overhead, then call that from your BEFORE trigger.

The only other option is to leave the `female` column alone, or else set it to some placeholder value. Then after the INSERT is confirmed successful by your application (and rows-affected is 1), then issue an UPDATE to set the `female` column's value.

But you can't do it in an AFTER trigger, full stop.

Comment: Suppose I executed `INSERT INTO couples (male) VALUES ('David')` with a before trigger such as `SELECT SLEEP(30)`. MySQL would wait for 30s and then continue with the following message: `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'David' for key 'PRIMARY'`. However, this is not the way I would like it to behave ...

Comment: Now, execute the same `INSERT INTO couples (male) VALUES ('David')` but with an after trigger such as `SELECT SLEEP(30)`. MySQL will return the same message of duplicated entry violation, but will not wait for 30s. Therefore, did not run the after trigger. This is the way I would like it to behave (but, instead of sleep, I need to update the rows values).

Comment: Well, you can't do that in a trigger. Sorry, but that's the way MySQL works. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: Is it possible to make a condition inside a before trigger stating the following: if there is no record with such male value then update the female counterpart, else do nothing ????

Comment: You could SELECT from the table, but that would create a race condition, because some other session might be inserting into the table concurrently.

Comment: Did not get it ... you mean that a concurrent session might cause issues with this before trigger?  I've though MySQL already take care with the atomicity of this operations ...

Comment: Another session might be inserting a row for 'David' but has not yet committed. Your BEFORE trigger can SELECT for such a row but won't be able to "see" an uncommitted row. But as soon as it tries to insert the row, it will conflict with the existing primary key. So there's no way to use a non-locking SELECT to be sure it's safe to INSERT the row.

Comment: Bill, I was thinking a lit bit more about this issue ... do you know if it is possible to "fire and forget" this statement?

Comment: @MarkMessa, No, there is no asynchronous processing feature in triggers. That would break ACID. If you want to do the update later than the trigger execution, do an UPDATE from your application after the INSERT returns.

Comment: _"If you want to do the update later than the trigger execution"_ I'm not considering separating the trigger execution from the rest. I'm considering 'fire and forget' everything: from `INSERT` to the `UPDATE` inside the before trigger (which by the way, I've implemented as you aforementioned and worked like a charm).

Comment: MySQL does not support an asynchronous client protocol until the X DevAPI. That's brand new and might not have widespread support, depending on your application language. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-introduction.html

Comment: But you can still spawn a worker thread or a child process or something like that in your application. You haven't stated what application language you use. Remember each thread needs its own dedicated connection to the MySQL server.

Comment: I'm using PHP. I was considering using: 1) `INSERT DELAYED` but it seems it doesn't work with InnoDB, 2) `mysql_unbuffered_query` or `mysqli_async` but they don't have effect on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, 3) MySQL Event but my provider set event_scheduler = "OFF"

Comment: Now I'm considering using cronjob but I don't think this is the kind of stuff cronjob was designed for ... I'm not sure it will work ...

Comment: _"worker thread or a child process or something like"_ Does PHP allow that?

Comment: I'm gonna take a while to read both, however, at first glance, it seems they both require installing 3rd party apps. Probably I won't have access to that.

Comment: Correct. It's probably easier to use a cron job, if you're stuck with PHP.

Comment: _"It's probably easier to use a cron job"_ Ok, in this case I would have to change the strategy in order to make it right. Instead of updating the female field as soon as a new male is insert (using your aforementioned before trigger), I would have to setup a cronjob to regularly update a batch of blank female fields. Let me know if you don't agree with this new strategy.